# At what speed does Twilio send DTMF tones when using the sendDigits command?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

My Twilio application dials our conference line, waits two seconds and then sends the conference PIN, followed by #.

`$dial->number('442031234567', ['sendDigits' => 'wwww123456789'] );`

I would like to be able to give my users an estimate of how long they should expect silence (while Twilio is sending the PIN digits) before the call is ready. I can make the call multiple times and time the delay, but that seems less exact that finding the underlying timings!

I know that each `w` character takes 0.5s, but I can't find any documentation for the amount of time each digit takes after that wait.

I've looked at Twilio's docs for [sendDigits](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits) and also [play](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play#examples-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I don't believe we give any guidance on how long the DTMF tones will take, but I believe they are a constant time. I would recommend trying it a few times, along with the system that you are dialling in to in order to estimate the time for your users.